# mod_rewrite: internal rewrite to (fake) clean URL not possible.

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, mod-proxy

This is more a *why* question.

I'm using a CMS that handles clean URLs via mod_rewrite out of the box.

Website has a section `/accessories` that now has to be renamed to `/store`.

Being on lazy mode, I just wanted to do an internal rewrite using mod_rewrite, so, when accessing `example.com/store/`, I want content served from `example.com/accessories`, transparently, without any external redirect.

So far, I've tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite /store to /accessories
RewriteRule ^store /accessories [L] #also tried with other flags like PT, N, C

# All below rules are provided by CMS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

But *nothing worked*.

The two only ways I could make this to work were:

- by internally rewriting the request to its corresponding "messy" URL, like this:

  `RewriteRule ^store /index.php?s=accessories [L]`
- by using mod_proxy and `ProxyPass` directive (which I discarded as solution, as  mod_proxy is not available on production server).

I've just come up to the conclusion that URLs cannot be internally rewritten to other (fake) clean URLs, while keeping the rewrite chaining alive. 
By "fake" I mean URL paths that are not real filesystem paths (usually, folders) or real files (like index.php).

So, question is: Why?

Comment: To clarify, do you want something like `/store/clothing/shirts/` to be rewritten to `/accessories/clothing/shirts/` (which is then passed on to index.php by later rewrite rules)? Either way you **definitely** don't want the `[L]` on the first rule, as that means "do not apply any subsequent mod_rewrite configuration to this request"

Comment: This is an excellent question which I wish would be addressed. It's weird that you can't do this.